# Keep rotation metadata with sharp node.js

Tags: javascript, sharp

I am working on an app that uses [sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/) for processing photos.
Currently, when we resize and then write to buffer an image with sharp resize and toBuffer, by default the two of them wipe the EXIF data. We want to remove all metadata except for **orientation** (if it exists).

I've read sharp's documentation and withMetadata seems to be the candidate to achieve what I want, the problem is that withMetadata preserves all metadata and I just want the **orientation** of the original image.

The original line of code is

`await this.sharpInstance.resize(maxDimension, maxDimension).max().toBuffer()`

I think that what I want is something like

`await this.sharpInstance.withMetadata().resize(maxDimension, maxDimension).max().withMetadata().toBuffer()`

but only for orientation metadata.

I would really appreciated some help to solve this. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `await this.sharpInstance.resize(maxDimension, maxDimension).max().withMetadata().toBuffer()` as Sharp [docs](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#withmetadata) about `withMetadata`.

Edited:

I got that. So as `withMetadata`, first we need to save the orientation metadata and then assign to output buffer later:

```js
// First, save the orientation for later use
const { orientation } = await this.sharpInstance.metadata();

// Then output to Buffer without metadata
// then create another Sharp instance 
// from output Buffer which doesn't have metadata
// and assign saved orientation along with it
sharp(this.sharpInstance.toBuffer())
    .withMetadata({ orientation }).toBuffer();
```

Comment: The problem of this is that it will preserve all existing metadata but what I need is to remove all of the metadata except for the orientation

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I was looking for. I got confused and thought that withMetadata kept all the attributes. Thanks you for the help!

Comment: My only doubt is, why not after saving the original orientation directly do: 

await this.sharpInstance.withMetadata({orientation}).resize(maxDimension, maxDimension).max().toBuffer() ?

Answer (score 7):

A workaround for those not specifically interested in keeping the file's original rotation plus rotation metadata: Rotate the image so that the file has no metadata, but the rotation is correct.

To do this, it is not necessary to read the metadata, if you call the `rotate()` method without parameters, it will look up the information in the metadata and perform the appropriate rotation.

Comment: This is actually a really helpful advice, especially the last sentence. Rotate without parameters do the necessary rotations (based on exif orientation), no need to do this "manually". This is useful in scenarios like im currently in: upload (exif rotated) image and add watermark to the uploaded image - with "composite" you need the define the gravity of the watermark, and this works funny when the image is rotated and you are using the "withMetadata" flag.
BTW I didn't find that info on sharp.js documentation, so thank you for this @Gonzalingui

Answer (score 0):

In my case the orientation was undefined.

`const { orientation } = await this.sharpInstance.metadata();`

But when installing `exif-reader` and analyzing the raw EXIF data, I found the orientation. The full code is here:

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
const image = sharp('input.jpg');
const exifReader = require('exif-reader');

image
    .metadata()
    .then(metadata => {

        const exif = exifReader(metadata.exif);

        return image
            .resize({
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                fit: 'inside',
                withoutEnlargement: true
            })
            .withMetadata({ orientation: exif.Image.Orientation})
            .toFile('output.jpg');

    });
```